# Upload and Resize Your Image link to mysql

Tags: php, sql, file, upload, image-uploading

I got this script from the net and changed few things to suit my needs but whatever I do I cannot put the link into my DB.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <h2>Upload and Resize Your Image</h2>
    <?php
    // index.php
    function generate_resized_image(){
        $max_dimension = 800; // Max new width or height, can not exceed this value.
        $dir = "../../upload123/"; // Directory to save resized image. (Include a trailing slash - /)
        // Collect the post variables.
        $postvars = array(
            "image"    => trim($_FILES["image"]["name"]),
            "image_tmp"    => $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
            "image_size"    => (int)$_FILES["image"]["size"],
            "image_max_width"    => (int)$_POST["image_max_width"],
            "image_max_height"   => (int)$_POST["image_max_height"]
        );
        // Array of valid extensions.
        $valid_exts = array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png");
        // Select the extension from the file.
        $ext = end(explode(".",strtolower(trim($_FILES["image"]["name"]))));
        // Check not larger than 175kb.
        if($postvars["image_size"] <= 1048576){
            // Check is valid extension.
            if(in_array($ext,$valid_exts)){
                if($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg"){
                    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($postvars["image_tmp"]);
                }
                else if($ext == "gif"){
                    $image = imagecreatefromgif($postvars["image_tmp"]);
                }
                else if($ext == "png"){
                    $image = imagecreatefrompng($postvars["image_tmp"]);
                }
                // Grab the width and height of the image.
                list($width,$height) = getimagesize($postvars["image_tmp"]);
                // If the max width input is greater than max height we base the new image off of that, otherwise we
                // use the max height input.
                // We get the other dimension by multiplying the quotient of the new width or height divided by
                // the old width or height.
                if($postvars["image_max_width"] > $postvars["image_max_height"]){
                    if($postvars["image_max_width"] > $max_dimension){
                        $newwidth = $max_dimension;
                    } else {
                        $newwidth = $postvars["image_max_width"];
                    }
                    $newheight = ($newwidth / $width) * $height;
                } else {
                    if($postvars["image_max_height"] > $max_dimension){
                        $newheight = $max_dimension;
                    } else {
                        $newheight = $postvars["image_max_height"];
                    }
                    $newwidth = ($newheight / $height) * $width;
                }
                // Create temporary image file.
                $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
                // Copy the image to one with the new width and height.
                 imagecopyresampled($tmp,$image,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
                // Create random 4 digit number for filename.
                $rand = rand(1000,9999);
                $filename = $dir.$rand.$postvars["image"];
                // Create image file with 100% quality.
                imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
                return "<strong>Image Preview:</strong><br/>
                    <img src=\"".$filename."\" border=\"0\" title=\"Resized  Image Preview\" style=\"padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px;background-color:#e0e0e0\" /><br/>
                    Resized image successfully generated. <a href=\"".$filename."\" target=\"_blank\"  name=\"Download your resized image now!\">Click here to download your image.</a>";
                imagedestroy($image);
                imagedestroy($tmp);
            } else {
                return "File size too large. Max allowed file size is 175kb.";
            }
        } else {
            return "Invalid file type. You must upload an image file. (jpg, jpeg, gif, png).";
        }
    }
    if(isset($_GET["do"])){
        if($_GET["do"] == "upload"){
           $upload_and_resize = generate_resized_image();
        } else {
        $upload_and_resize = "";
    }
    } else {
        $upload_and_resize = "";
    }
    ?>

                <form action="./upload.php?do=upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" width="100">Max Width:</td>
                        <input name="image_max_width" type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="400" />
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Image:</td>
                        <td align="left"><input type="file" name="image" size="40" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2">
                            <ol style="margin:0;padding:3px 0px 3px 15px">
                                <li>Max file size: 175 KB.</li>
                                <li>Allowed extensions: jpg, jpeg, gif, png.</li>
                                <li>Max Dimension: <em>800</em>px.</li>
                            </ol>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!" class="submit" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>

            <div id="upload">
                <?php echo $upload_and_resize; ?>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

So I tried various positions but none helped this is what I need to put in my Db which is simple table 1- ID 2- slime (slime is where the image link goes)

```
    $filenamex=$filename;
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","USER","PASS");
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("myDB", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO acc1 (slime)
    VALUES
    ('$filenamex')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_close($con)
```

Comment: Please stop using the deprecated `mysql_` functions and instead use `mysqli` or `PDO`. I personally prefer `PDO` as it works on more than just MySQL

Comment: Thank you for your tips, pleas do you have a solution for my problem also. Wuld be gretful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the generate_resized_image function to just return the file path :

```
<?php
    // index.php
    function generate_resized_image(){
        $max_dimension = 800; // Max new width or height, can not exceed this value.
        $dir = "../../upload123/"; // Directory to save resized image. (Include a trailing slash - /)
        // Collect the post variables.
        $postvars = array(
            "image"    => trim($_FILES["image"]["name"]),
            "image_tmp"    => $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
            "image_size"    => (int)$_FILES["image"]["size"],
            "image_max_width"    => (int)$_POST["image_max_width"],
            "image_max_height"   => (int)$_POST["image_max_height"]
        );
        // Array of valid extensions.
        $valid_exts = array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png");
        // Select the extension from the file.
        $ext = end(explode(".",strtolower(trim($_FILES["image"]["name"]))));
        // Check not larger than 175kb.
        if($postvars["image_size"] <= 1048576){
            // Check is valid extension.
            if(in_array($ext,$valid_exts)){
                if($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg"){
                    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($postvars["image_tmp"]);
                }
                else if($ext == "gif"){
                    $image = imagecreatefromgif($postvars["image_tmp"]);
                }
                else if($ext == "png"){
                    $image = imagecreatefrompng($postvars["image_tmp"]);
                }
                // Grab the width and height of the image.
                list($width,$height) = getimagesize($postvars["image_tmp"]);
                // If the max width input is greater than max height we base the new image off of that, otherwise we
                // use the max height input.
                // We get the other dimension by multiplying the quotient of the new width or height divided by
                // the old width or height.
                if($postvars["image_max_width"] > $postvars["image_max_height"]){
                    if($postvars["image_max_width"] > $max_dimension){
                        $newwidth = $max_dimension;
                    } else {
                        $newwidth = $postvars["image_max_width"];
                    }
                    $newheight = ($newwidth / $width) * $height;
                } else {
                    if($postvars["image_max_height"] > $max_dimension){
                        $newheight = $max_dimension;
                    } else {
                        $newheight = $postvars["image_max_height"];
                    }
                    $newwidth = ($newheight / $height) * $width;
                }
                // Create temporary image file.
                $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
                // Copy the image to one with the new width and height.
                 imagecopyresampled($tmp,$image,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
                // Create random 4 digit number for filename.
                $rand = rand(1000,9999);
                $filename = $dir.$rand.$postvars["image"];
                // Create image file with 100% quality.
                imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //here is the change
                return $filename; //return the new image path
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------
                imagedestroy($image);
                imagedestroy($tmp);
            } else {
                return "File size too large. Max allowed file size is 175kb.";
            }
        } else {
            return "Invalid file type. You must upload an image file. (jpg, jpeg, gif, png).";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Then put your sql code into a function something like:

```
// you can modify this to handle errors better, this is just for example
function saveToDb($filename)
{
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "USER", "PASS");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("myDB", $con);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO acc1 (slime)
    VALUES
    ('$filename')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    mysql_close($con);
}
```

Then this part of the code would be where most of the action happens :

```
if(isset($_GET["do"])){
        if($_GET["do"] == "upload"){
           $uploaded = generate_resized_image();//now just returns path to new image
           $mysql = saveToDb($uploaded);
           if (!$mysql) {
            //handle error
           }
        } else {
        $upload_and_resize = "";
    }
    } else {
        $upload_and_resize = "";
    }
```

now that saving is accomplished you'll have to fix this div as the function no longer returns any html code.

```
<div id="upload">
    <?php echo $upload_and_resize; ?>
</div>
```

Good luck.

P.S. it might be time to start with object oriented PHP.

Comment: Well, actually you should put your return statement after the imagedestroy calls, otherwise the memory used by the images will not be freed (well, at least not until the script ends anyway).

Comment: @wimvds ahhhh.. optimization. That's a different question :)